# MS ACCESS .NET - Any way to get the remainder of a division without using Modulo?

Tags: sql, .net, ms-access, modulo

As the title suggests, I have to get the remainder of a division in an SQL query, but the issue is that the MS Access .NET Framework does not recognize Modulus, so I cannot use that.

Comment: Why not do the divide, truncate so you can get the whole number and deduct that off the divide result?

Comment: It's kind of complicated, I'm calculating a field that looks like "5 days, 2 hours and 3 minutes". So it's effectively 3 DateDiff functions with the last two using the Mod function. It's always a possibility, but it would cause me to redo a lot of my work and I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: Access' db engine supports `Mod`.  Can't you use it in your Access SQL ... `SELECT [Total minutes] Mod 60` ... regardless of what .NET recognizes?

Comment: Access' db engine does, but I am using an Access DB file in an ASP.NET Web Site project. I realized Access supports it because when executing my query I get the result I want, but it throws a warning every time since .NET does not recognize mod. This becomes an issue when I have to generate reports and stuff based upon datasets with queries containing mod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around the warnings being thrown by .NET by generating the query's columns in my DataSet then putting the query with the Mod in it. This way the columns are properly filled. ASP.NET was not letting me generate the columns due to the Mod in the query but removing it then putting it back allowed me to work around it.